# Creating a postfix alias "all@domain.tld" to send to all users of a domain

Tags: postfix, alias

I'm using Postfix + Dovecot with a MySQL database as backend and PostfixAdmin to administrate users and domains. Now I'm looking for an *easy* and *automated* approach to define per-domain alias of the pattern `all@domain.tld` with will resolve to all users of the given domain. I want to set this up once, and it shall keep working as expected even if accounts are added or deleted – so creating a file with a list of accounts manually, or using some mailing list are no options.

It should be pretty easy to retrieve all existing users for a given domain from the database:

```
SELECT username
  FROM vmail
 WHERE domain='%d';
```

(with `%d` being the placeholder for the domain). But how can I tell postfix to do so for mails directed to `all@domain.tld`, and of course only when such a mail comes from a trusted source (`permit_sasl_authenticated`, `permit_mynetworks`?)?

I've googled for a few hours now, but all I found were either "catch-alls" (just the opposite from what I want), solutions based on shell-scripts (walking the resp. domain directory), or using mailing-list approaches – none of that fitting my needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `virtual_alias_maps` to define alias all@example.com. Here the format used by [virtual 5](http://www.postfix.org/virtual.5.html).

```
pattern address1, address2, address3, ...
```

So you need to construct query to concat all rows. Taken from this thread: [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field), you can use this query.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN active='1' THEN username ELSE NULL END separator ', ')
  FROM vmail
 WHERE DOMAIN='%d'
   AND '%s'='all@%d'
```

This needs to go to your `mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf` and can be appended to the existing query using `UNION` – so the result looks e.g. like this:

```
query = SELECT goto FROM alias WHERE address='%s' AND active = '1' UNION 
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN active='1' THEN username ELSE NULL END separator ', ')
  FROM vmail
 WHERE DOMAIN='%d'
   AND '%s'='all@%d'
```

(might need to be all in one line – formatting here is just applied to make it easier to read).

---

To allow only permit_mynetworks and permit_sasl_authenticated, put the restriction in following order

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =  ....
                        permit_mynetworks
                        permit_sasl_authenticated
                        check_recipient_access regexp:/etc/postfix/restrict.all.alias
                        reject_unauth_destination
```

In /etc/postfix/restrict.all.alias, define

```
/^all@/  REJECT access denied
```

It will permit email to all@domain when sent from mynetworks or sent by authenticated user, but reject after that.

Comment: That sounds like the approach I am after! But few open questions: 1) where to put the query in (and how to tell postfix to use it), 2) the "all=%u" part seems to break the query, as there's no "all" field (is that needed, and what for? Omitting it seems to yield the correct result: all users of that domain), 3) doesn't the created field require an alias (and if so, what specific name)? Oh, and 4) mustn't the regexp be `/^all@/` – as otherwise it would also match `pitfall@`?

Comment: For 1) I assume I've got to add it to `mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf`, which already has a `query=SELECT goto FROM alias WHERE address='%s' AND active = '1'`. Guess that `active='1'` part must be added to your query as well, but [in a different way](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/30952/30273), as the alias shouldn't catch inactive accounts. Obviously, `%s` then must match our `all@` somehow (`WHERE '%s'='all@%d'`), and then it could be connected by a `UNION`, [like this](http://pastebin.com/SRLyUp4G)? (PS: that BTW would take care for 2+3 as well I'd say)

Comment: Oh, one more: `check_recipient_access pcre:` leads to `error: unsupported dictionary type: pcre`, that must be `check_recipient_access regexp:`. Adjusted the restrict file to `/^all@/  REJECT access denied`, and got a `554 5.7.1 <all@domain.tld>: Recipient address rejected: not permitted` from remote. From localhost, it was accepted – and ended up in all expected mailboxes (for the addressed domain), and nowhere else – Yeeha! \o/ So do you want to update your answer with my corrections, or shall I do so? Meanwhile +25 for you :)